# How do I change global hotkeys / keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: 11.10, shortcut-keys

In 11.04 I change global hotkeys using gconf-editor, In 11.10 there no this software, and I think if developers remove it from base compection, maybe they do this configuration in Control Panel, but I can't find it

Also I'd try dconf-editor - and can't find hotkeys there.

Comment: If you are looking all keyboard shortcuts, type `keyboard` in launcher hit enter to open. You can find all shortcuts under `shortcut` tab. If you i missed understand you, my apology :)

Comment: It's helped me!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are looking all keyboard shortcuts, type `keyboard` in launcher hit enter to open it. You can find all shortcuts under shortcut tab.

[image]

Comment: my 1 cent: Typing `keyboard` opens Keyboard Layout for me. I had to type `keyboard s` to get the desired dialog window.