# Can I change the default terminal colors?

Tags: command-line, colors

I don't want to change the default colors as such, I want to use a custom color.  For example I want to lighten the blue as it is too dark.  I don't want to change it to a different color, but make it lighter.
Is that possible in linux?  I can change the colors running linux sub system in Windows using the command prompt properties and adjusting the RGB values of each color, but wanted a similar change in pure linux itself.

Thanks :)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/809590/automatically-get-different-terminal-colors-each-time-i-open-terminal/811290

Comment: do you mean you want to configure those colors which are predefined under "built in schemes"??

Comment: Like yourself one of the first things I had to do for Ubuntu on Windows was remap an unreadable blue to more readable cyan. But I never had that problem with Ubuntu on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I Understood your Question in a right way..

there is built in option in gnome-terminal under Edit-->Preferences-->Colors-->Use transparent background

[image]

Comment: Yes, I wanted to edit the pre-defined colors.  I haven't tinkered around much with Linux much yet, but have been using the Ubuntu under Windows 10 option and have since installed Linux on 3 PC's now.  They all seem to have a dark blue that is almost impossible to read.  I'm still transitioning from Windows to Linux and learning where the Linux alternatives are. Thanks for the easy solution :)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1175987/739431 for a command line way..